# how to use gridbag to make half of my JFrame a text area and the other half buttons?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to make a JFrame to display a GUI like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2POFs.png
(im not allowed to embed pictures)

the blank spcaces are the same X and Y dimentions, 
the buttons are the same X and Y dimentions, 
JTextArea is half of the frame.

```
public static JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Launcher " + version);
public static GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
public static JTextArea news = new JTextArea();
public static JButton launchGame = new JButton("Launch Game");
public static JButton settings = new JButton("Settings");
public static JButton exitGame = new JButton("Exit");

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    news.setEditable(false);
    news.setBounds(0, 0, (screenSize.width - 500) / 2,  screenSize.height - 400);
    news.append("                        NEWS:\n");
    news.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.gray, Color.black));

    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.setBounds(300, 200, screenSize.width - 500,  screenSize.height - 400);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    c.weighty = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridheight = 3;
    frame.add(news, c);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    frame.add(launchGame, c);
    c.gridy = 1;
    frame.add(settings, c);
            c.gridy = 2;
    frame.add(exitGame, c);
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have?  It looks basically right.  You might move the setVisible down to the end, though.

Comment: grid bag is not necessary, its what seems most practical for layout managers, but then again I don't even know most of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? I added/modified the following in your button constraints:

```
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10); // 10 is the marginal
```

And here is the full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    news.setEditable(false);
    news.append("                        NEWS:\n");
    news.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.gray, Color.black));

    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    c.weighty = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridheight = 3;
    frame.add(news, c);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10); // 10 is the marginal
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    frame.add(launchGame, c);
    c.gridy = 1;
    frame.add(settings, c);
    c.gridy = 2;
    frame.add(exitGame, c);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Here is a similar layout using `BoxLayout` instead (easier to work with I think):

```
private static JComponent buildButtons() {
    for (JButton button : Arrays.asList(launchGame, settings, exitGame)) {
        button.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    Box b = Box.createVerticalBox();
    b.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    b.add(launchGame);
    b.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    b.add(settings);
    b.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    b.add(exitGame);
    b.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));

    return b;
}

static JComponent buildUI() {
    Box b = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    b.add(news);
    b.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    b.add(buildButtons());
    b.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));

    return b;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    news.setEditable(false);
    news.append("                        NEWS:\n");
    news.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.gray, Color.black));

    frame.add(buildUI());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: What's he point of using setBounds when you're going to override it with a layout manager? I know the code comes from the OP, but we should try a guide users to use appropriate practices, IMHO

Comment: Sure, I went for the minimal diff thing. I'll just remove the line. If a certain dimension of the news component is wanted setPreferredSize would do the trick.

Comment: it doesn't really matter to me a whole lot how big the frame really is, its just a launcher

Comment: That worked great, except i think frame.pack(); is causing the frame to be to small... the buttons say "..." unless I drag the window out more.

Comment: That's not ok. Remember to pack and setVisible after all components have been added. Does that change anything? Which did you go for (Box or GridBag)?

Comment: oh I see whats going on, the text area expands based on how much text is in it >.<  i left out a part of code that gets a string from my website and appends to the text area, and it causes the buttons to be shrink, ill try the setPreferedSize..  and gridbag

Comment: I'm going to give you a +1 as your answer is essentially correct (I'm just picky and would like to see it a little cleaned up ;))

Answer (score 2):

First of all...

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
```

Isn't what I think you want to do.  I think the fill should be at least `HORIZONTAL`

Secondly...

You could use `Insets` to adjust the space between the components, something like

[image]

```
public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new FormPane());
                frame.setSize(500, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected static class FormPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea news = new JTextArea();
        private JButton launchGame = new JButton("Launch Game");
        private JButton settings = new JButton("Settings");
        private JButton exitGame = new JButton("Exit");

        public FormPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            news.setEditable(false);
            news.append("                        NEWS:\n");
            news.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.gray, Color.black));

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 0.25;
            add(news, gbc);

            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 50, 0, 50);
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridx++;            
            add(launchGame, gbc);
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(settings, gbc);
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(exitGame, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

I might also be inclined to to place the buttons in there own container (like a `JPanel`) and maybe use a `GridLayout` to lay them out, then use the above suggestion to lay the text area and button container.

This isolates the individual layout needs without further complicating the layout...

Comment: They're essentially the same idea, I just added some minor tweaks and comments ;)

Comment: For a 50/50 layout I would use `GridLayout`, but then, I think your layout is better visually and has a certain 'balance'.

Comment: I agree, `GridLayout` with a container of buttons (using another `GridLayout`) with an `EmptyBorder` would also work